# CodeIgniter, array do not accept string after $this->db->get

Tags: arrays, codeigniter, object

**According this code in the model Etablissements_commanditaires_m :**

```
public  function ajouter()
   {
... code ...
$recuperer = $this->db->get($this->table)->result_array();
$recuperer['quantite_lignes'] = $this->db->count_all_results($this->table);
$recuperer['number'] = 5;
$recuperer['text'] = 'blabla';
```

The last line $recuperer['text'] = 'blabla'; makes error.

But the line $recuperer['number'] = 5; do not makes error.

The coming errors are : Illegal string offset or Undefined offset: 0

**And this code in the controller :**

```
$etablissements_commanditaires = $this->etablissements_commanditaires_m->ajouter();
$html['quantite_lignes'] = $etablissements_commanditaires['quantite_lignes'];
... code ...
$i=0;
foreach ($etablissements_commanditaires as $enregistrement)
            {
            echo 'aa'.$enregistrement['id_etablissement_payeur'].'bb'; // Makes the first error.
            ...
            }
```

The errors are :

```
<p>Severity: Warning</p>
<p>Message:  Illegal string offset 'id_etablissement_payeur'</p>
<p>Filename: ETABLISSEMENTS_COMMANDITAIRES/etablissements_commanditaires_c.php</p>
<p>Line Number: 240</p>

</div>aa5bb<div style="border:1px solid #990000;padding-left:20px;margin:0 0 10px 0;">

<h4>A PHP Error was encountered</h4>

<p>Severity: Warning</p>
<p>Message:  Illegal string offset 'id_etablissement_payeur'</p>
<p>Filename: ETABLISSEMENTS_COMMANDITAIRES/etablissements_commanditaires_c.php</p>
<p>Line Number: 243</p>

</div><div style="border:1px solid #990000;padding-left:20px;margin:0 0 10px 0;">

<h4>A PHP Error was encountered</h4>

<p>Severity: Warning</p>
<p>Message:  Illegal string offset 'id_etablissement_payeur'</p>
<p>Filename: ETABLISSEMENTS_COMMANDITAIRES/etablissements_commanditaires_c.php</p>
<p>Line Number: 254</p>

</div><div style="border:1px solid #990000;padding-left:20px;margin:0 0 10px 0;">

<h4>A PHP Error was encountered</h4>

<p>Severity: Notice</p>
<p>Message:  Undefined offset: 0</p>
<p>Filename: ETABLISSEMENTS_COMMANDITAIRES/etablissements_commanditaires_c.php</p>
<p>Line Number: 260</p>
```

How can I set a string to $recuperer['text'], without having error ?

**An other case looking to be the same problem, and then wondering if my CodeIgniter/PHP is ok ?**

PHP => PHP Version 5.5.9-1ubuntu4.3

CodeIgniter => 2.2.0

```
$this->db->select('id_etablissement_payeur, nom');
$this->db->where('id_etablissement_payeur',$enregistrement['id_etablissement_payeur']);
$get_RESULTAT_etablissements_payeurs = $this->db->get('etablissements_payeurs');
$result_etablissements_payeurs = $get_RESULTAT_etablissements_payeurs->result_array();

echo '<pre>';
print_r($result_etablissements_payeurs);
echo '</pre>';

echo $result_etablissements_payeurs[0]['id_etablissement_payeur'] . ' - '; //Line Number: 279
echo $result_etablissements_payeurs[0]['nom']; //Line Number: 280
```

The print_r gives the good result with offset 0 :

```
 <pre>Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id_etablissement_payeur] => 4
            [nom] => Etablissement payeur N° 4
        )

)
</pre>4 - Etablissement payeur N° 4<pre>Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id_etablissement_payeur] => 1
            [nom] => Etablissement payeur N° 1
        )

)
</pre>1 - Etablissement payeur N° 1<pre>Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id_etablissement_payeur] => 1
            [nom] => Etablissement payeur N° 1
        )

)
etc.
```

But the 2 echo makes an  Undefined offset: 0 error :

```
<p>Severity: Notice</p>
<p>Message:  Undefined offset: 0</p>
<p>Filename: ETABLISSEMENTS_COMMANDITAIRES/etablissements_commanditaires_c.php</p>
<p>Line Number: 279</p>

</div> - <div style="border:1px solid #990000;padding-left:20px;margin:0 0 10px 0;">

<h4>A PHP Error was encountered</h4>

<p>Severity: Notice</p>
<p>Message:  Undefined offset: 0</p>
<p>Filename: ETABLISSEMENTS_COMMANDITAIRES/etablissements_commanditaires_c.php</p>
<p>Line Number: 280</p>

</div><div style="border:1px solid #990000;padding-left:20px;margin:0 0 10px 0;">
etc.
```

This is very strange, because offset 0 does exist, or I missed something somewhere.

Any idea ?

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue for the second question "An other case looking ..."

The result table of my model looks as :

```
[0] => Array
[1] => Array
[2] => Array
[3] => Array
[quantite_lignes] => 4
```

Then, when I put this table in a foreach(), the last index makes errors because it does not contain an array.

Maybe the first question is the same way ... did not look at it again yet, coming soon ...

Back,

I found the issue about the first question, it was linked to the second question (foreach() issue).